# Use a method that is only defined in a subclass

Tags: php, laravel

I have a method :

```
protected function chooseAndUpdateParentFight(Fight $fight, Fight $parentFight)
{
    $fighterToUpdate = $fight->getParentFighterToUpdate();
    ...
}
```

I have 2 kinds of fights : `PreliminaryFight` and `DirectEliminationFight`

Both are subclass of `Fight`

thing is definition of  `getParentFighterToUpdate()` only exists in both subclass, but not in `Fight` class, so I get:

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2443:
Call to undefined method 
Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getParentFighterToUpdate()
```

How should I do???

EDIT: Here are both getParentFighterToUpdate method:

DirectEliminationFight Class:

```
public function getParentFighterToUpdate()
{
    $childrenGroup = $this->group->parent->children;
    foreach ($childrenGroup as $key => $children) {
        $childFight = $children->fights->get(0);
        if ($childFight->id == $this->id) {
            if ($key % 2 == 0) {
                return "c1";
            }
            if ($key % 2 == 1) {
                return "c2";
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

PreliminaryFight Class

```
public function getParentFighterToUpdate()
 {
    $childrenGroup = $this->group->parent->children;
    foreach ($childrenGroup as $key => $children) {
        $childFights = $children->fights;
        dd($childFights);
        // Still writing it
    }
    return null;
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
/**
 * Update fighter if it is possible
 * @param $fightsByRound
 */
protected function updateParentFight(Collection $fightsByRound)
{

    foreach ($fightsByRound as $fight) {
        $parentGroup = $fight->group->parent;
        if ($parentGroup == null) break;
        $parentFight = $parentGroup->fights->get(0);
        $this->chooseAndUpdateParentFight($fight, $parentFight);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show both `getParentFighterToUpdate()` methods?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: A rough and ready approach would be to define `getParentFighterToUpdate ` in the `Fight` model and then just something like: `if(class_basename(static::class) == 'PreliminaryFight')` to split them up. That being said is there a reason that you're not passing one of the sub classes to `chooseAndUpdateParentFight`?

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to cast Fight $fight to PrelimiminaryFight::class

Answer (score 0):

You could use an interface that defines the `getParentFighterToUpdate` method and have the `Fight` class implement it.

But the actual problem seems to be lying somewhere else, since you're apparently passing an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` to your method, not a `Fight`. Check your method call as to whether or not you're passing the correct variables

Comment: Interface would declare it but not define it. Also, I don't want Fight to implement it, just subclasses. The second problem is not a problem, Fight is a model, but it will work if I can solve this

Comment: Since PHP doesn't have static typechecking, that method call should work if the given object has the method, even if Fight doesn't declare it. Can you try a get_class or var_dump on your passed Parameters and see if they're correct? You could also try removing the type hint and seeing if that works

Comment: I already tried to remove the typehint, but with no success. get_class must be Fight type, as I force in typehint, don't you agree?

Comment: this is exactly the fact, given object ( Fight ) doesn't have this method, because it is defined in children

Comment: Well, it has to be Fight or a Subclass of Fight, and it seems like the object you're passing does not implement the method, that's why get_class would be interesting

Comment: getClass($fight) gives "Xoco70\KendoTournaments\Models\Fight"

Comment: And what does `method_exists($fight, "getParentFighterToUpdate")` return?

Comment: it returns false

Comment: Can you provide the code where you call `chooseAndUpdateParentFight`? It seems like you're passing a `Fight` object, not one of your subclasses

Comment: yes, this is exactly what happen. Code is already in question.

Comment: The problem is not within the implementation of `getParentFighterToUpdate `, we need to see your `chooseAndUpdateParentFight` method call

Comment: oo, ok sorry, misunderstood you. I will add it question

Comment: I have updated my question with  chooseAndUpdateParentFight

Comment: You should check the class of $fight and $parentFight in that method as well. Also, you should consider making `Fight` abstract so that you can only instantiate the subclasses